# Which suffix is in the word "precede": -ede or -cede?

Tags: affixes

Which suffix is in the word "precede": -ede or -cede?

I don't have an idea whether -ede or -cede is suffix in the words like precede, intercede, etc.

Comment: Look them up in a dictionary? Or even just Etymonline. The works has been down for all of us to benefit from.

Comment: @DanBron - not that easy, the just mention the prefix, not the suffix. https://www.etymonline.com/word/precede

Comment: @user240918 Because it only has a prefix and a root. That’s part of what I wanted OP to start discovering for themselves.

Comment: @DanBron - yes but the root itself has a suffix, at least in Latin  *-ere*

Comment: @user240918 Which doesn’t appear in *precede*.

Comment: @DanBron -  having said that, is *-ede* a suffix?

Comment: @user240918 All this is spelled out in the etymology. I don’t know what you and I are discussing.

Answer (score 1):

Eugene, you seem to be confused about what a suffix is (and probably don't know what a root is, either).  So here are two sites to help you navigate those concepts:

***[Root](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/root%20word)***:

> A root word has no prefix or suffix — it's the most basic part of a word. The root word at the heart of *conformity*, for example, is *form*.

***[Suffix](https://www.thoughtco.com/common-suffixes-in-english-1692725)***:

> A suffix is a letter or a group of letters attached to the end of a word to form a new word or to change the grammatical function (or part of speech) of the original word. For example, the verb *read* is made into the noun *reader* by adding the suffix *-er*. Similarly, *read* is made into the adjective *readable* by adding the suffix *-able*.